# Any solution for OAuth Google without webviews

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

> I'm developping an app in which I'd like the user to log with fb or google account. So far I've been using Xamarin Auth which provides a OAuth authentification with webviews.

As I want to realease the app on markets, I checked the future deprecation of this component. Google made an annoucement saying that they will block any OAuth in webviews from April 20th 2017 ...

Have you find a solution to Xamarin Auth for google sign in ?

I've seen a component for FireBase published by xamarin 25 days ago ... but I wonder if it will work for forms as it is a xamarin android component ... And I'd like to keep the logic that "forms is crossplatform" and I do not want to use a plugin for each project.

I've been seeking the web but no solutions...

I'm glad if someone's found something or a workaround without components if there are none ..

Answer (score 0):

Go and visit Xamarin.Auth repo, Xamarin Forums, Xamarin Chat (community team) and you will realise that since nuget versio 1.4.0 Xamarin.Auth supports NativeUI (Chrome Custom Tabs and Safari ViewController).

1.5.0-alpha has Xamarin.Forms support (Android and iOS, Windows not tested thoroughly)

Regarding Firebase - There are Firebase Auth Components for Android and iOS

https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebaseiosauth

and

https://components.xamarin.com/view/firebase-auth

For Xamarin.Forms wrap those with DependencyService or CustomRenderer.

Comment: I am using this url its perfectly working but i need to Token, Userid, Name https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/google-services/SigninQuickstart/SigninQuickstart/MainActivity.cs

Comment: The question was

> Have you find a solution to Xamarin Auth for google sign in ?

and that sample is for Google APIs, so Google's SDKs. With DependencyService it can be adapted for Xamarin.Forms, but then there is still iOS missing.

Comment: I was trying to xamarin.auth but not solve the problem then after I will Find a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

I did this without Xamarin.Auth and WebViews.

1.Open URL with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id&{other_params}" in external browser - e.g.

```
Device.OpenUri(...);
```

2.Listen to App Starts from a redirect URI Like "yourapp-youtube"
under iOS in AppDelegate.cs

```
override bool OpenUrl(...)
```

3.Parse the response from youtube. It will contain a data string(I think base64) with Token information etc.

4.Deserialize and Save this to a database

5.check regularly if the token is expired (if expired call the refresh endpoint "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" - e.g. with HttpClient directly from PCL)

Comment: what is My First Stape